# Should the result of PackagePart.GetStream() be disposed?

Tags: .net, system.io.packaging

Should the caller of [PackagePart.GetStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.packagepart.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) dispose the returned Stream object?  Or does this method return an object that could be reused?  The documentation doesn't say.

[Looking at the .NET source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/IO/Packaging/PackagePart.cs,aa00933b816cf234,references), almost every place calling `GetStream()` disposes the result, either directly or indirectly.  My best guess at an answer is that the result of GetStream() can always be disposed, but doesn't necessarily have to be if the parent PackagePart is disposed.

Comment: Disposables should always be disposed. This notion that you may dispose it if you wish, or you may sweep it under the carpet if it is too much of a hassle, is the source of tons of errors. When there are two ways of going about something, pick one strategy and stick with it, (and even enforce it if you can,) and everything will suddenly become much easier in your life.  And since the "never dispose" strategy is not viable, "always dispose" is the way to go.